# JavaScript doesn't block DOM constructing

Tags: javascript

I have this html:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>

    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I specifically made `index.js` as a big file such as 1MB. and testing this on slow network of google chrome.

Now, the thing is when I run the website, TEST immediatelly appears on the screen. page still is loading(as js file is big), but TEST appears immediatelly.

I've read somewhere that: `The entire DOM CONSTRUCTION process is halted until the script finishes executing.` If that's the case, **why does 'TEST' appear on the screen?** DOM construction is not finished because browser encountered the script and how does it know that DOM is ready after it encountered `<h1>TEST</h1>`.

**In my opinion:** TEST should be appearing after the index.js has been loaded.

Comment: Well your script is included after "TEST", right ? Then it's normal it is constructed before your script is executed

Comment: On which browser are you testing?

Comment: Chrome. look at what I've read: The entire DOM CONSTRUCTION process is halted until the script finishes executing. This means that DOM is not ready because it encountered script tag and didn't move on to closing </body> and </html> tag.

Comment: Yes, it is halted. But when the parsing gets to the script tag, the "TEST" string has already been parsed and constructed. *Browsers don't wait for the whole page to be parsed before constructing it.*

Comment: Try adding style for that H1. Markup is loaded first and **[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)** event is fired. Then resources are loaded, styles are applied and then window ready is fired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only *future* DOM construction halts when a script is being downloaded/parsed. DOM elements which have already been parsed (such as your `<h1>`), which come *before* the script tag, remain in the DOM - the downloading of a script does not result in them being removed until the script is finished.

If you had switched it around:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

it would take a bit of time for `TEST` to be displayed, as you're expecting, because here, the `<script>` comes *before* the `TEST`, so the script needs to be parsed before the TEST appears.

Comment: So, what happens in my example is, when it reaches script tag, browser thinks that dom construction is done and shows it to the screen?

Comment: No, when it reaches the script tag, DOM construction for the `<h1>TEST</h1>` *has already occurred*. The browser knows that it's not done yet; it just pauses the process (displaying what's been parsed so far) and waits for the script to finish before proceeding to parse stuff below the `<script>` tag.

Comment: So, fully dom is not constructed yet, but browser still decides to show partially constructed Dom?

Comment: Yeah. It's not even a `<script>` thing - the browser renders what it has of the DOM *as soon as it can*, even if things haven't been fully downloaded yet, This is pretty easy to see on huge pages ([example](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)), which doesn't even have any JS of significant note

Comment: so it's something like that. we had partial DOM for <h1>TEST</h1> , then when the script is done, and parser continued parsing html below script tag, browser took the old dom, parser built new dom below script tag, and appended it to the old dom?

Comment: It's all the same DOM that the browser appends to. Sometimes it can append to it all at once, like with a small page with nothing to download, sometimes it appends to it in bursts.

Comment: when does executing script tag for download happen? in tokenization phase?

Comment: Once the browser sees the `<script>`, it starts downloading it, then it parses it, compiles it, and executes it. *Then*, after all synchronous code in the script is done, and after the microtask queue is empty, the browser goes on to continue parsing HTML below the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207340/discussion-between-nika-kurashvili-and-certainperformance).